# How do i check db records for 1 day digest interms of current milliseconds

Tags: java

I am working on a scheduler, the job of this scheduler pull records from a table and check with CreatedTS in terms of current miliseconds and say the user has daily digest or weekly digests. how do i this

**DB sample record**

```
ID Message CreatedTS

1   MSG1    2020-05-22 09:06:38
```

**My sample java code**

```
private static final long ONEDAYMILISEC=86400000;
private static final long ONEWEEKMILISEC=604800000

 Date dbDate = simpleDateFormatter.parse(eachJSONObject.getString("createdts"));
 long dbmillis = dbDate.getTime();
 if(ONEDAYMILISEC<=(curmiliseconds-dbmillis) && eachJSONObject.getString("DigestType").equals("Daily") ){
dailydigestsMap.put(eachJSONObject.getString("inviteeemail"), "Present");
}else if(ONEWEEKMILISEC<=(curmiliseconds-dbmillis) && eachJSONObject.getString("DigestType").equals("Weekly") ){
  dailydigestsMap.put(eachJSONObject.getString("inviteeemail"), "Present");
 }
```

The above db record i want to check comes under daily digest or weekly digest

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Comment: Tim checking if conditions are failing

Comment: That is very vague, could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Updated the sample data

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the functionality in the more modern java.time package and also to work with proper date/time classes rather than milliseconds.

The following code parses a date string and checks if it is within the last day or week.

```
String createTs = "2020-05-23 09:06:38";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime creaTime = LocalDateTime.parse(createTs, formatter);
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

if (now.minusDays(1).isBefore(creaTime)) {
    System.out.println("Daily");
} else if (now.minusWeeks(1).isBefore(creaTime)) {
    System.out.println("Weekly");
} else {
    System.out.println("Neither");
}
```

Personally I think this way of checking is a little bit strange but that is how it is done in the question.